# Docker container not accessible in host machine

Tags: networking, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Some of my containers are running a web server (PHP, NodeJS) in production.

If we take the example of the NodeJS container, this is its configuration

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  webapp:
    build: .
    volumes_from:
     - data
    links:
     - db:db
     - redis:redis
    ports:
      - '8080:3000'
    restart: always

  ...
```

With this configuration, I'm able to access to my webapp through `http://example.com:8080/` but I cannot access on my host machine with

```
$ curl localhost:8080
(Time-out)
```

I have a *Nginx* server on my host with this configuration:

**example.com.conf**

```
upstream webapp {
   server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   HOST $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://webapp;
  }

}
```

But acceding to `http://example.com/` throw a 504 Gateway Time-out.

If I try to change port configuration in my `docker-compose.yml` by `'127.0.0.1:8080:3000'` the problem still here but cannot access to `http://example.com` (and `http://example.com:8080` but it is the result I want).

This is very strange and I don't have the problem running my app on a fresh server.
I'm searching for the root of this issue.

Thanks for your support.

EDIT:

```
$ netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address        State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:59712        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:33293        0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Web server has to be listening on port 3000 but I have

```
$ docker-compose logs
webapp_1  | Express server listening on port 3000 in production mode
```

The server is also running...

```
$ docker port webapp_1
3000/tcp -> 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Comment: shouldn't this be `curl http://example.com:8080/`?

Comment: Are you using Docker Machine?

Comment: @stacksonstacks : I want my container only be accessible in local and redirect on the public domain with Nginx.

Comment: @NguyenSyThanhSon : I'm not.

Comment: So without docker-machine, you're running directly on a Linux host? Would you verify the container is listening on the port, with `sudo netstat -atp` when the container is down and then up, and `docker port $container_name` on your container name. Are there any logs from your container? Does example.com resolve to an IP address of the host you are testing on?

Comment: @BMitch check my edit

Comment: Doesn't look like you ran the `sudo netstat -atp`, and the netstat you did provide doesn't show the webserver listening. Looks like you only answered the `docker port` question, and the problem appears to be elsewhere.

Comment: @BMitch Because `netstat -atp` shows the same first line of `netstat -tulnp`

Comment: Without `sudo` you don't get processes. And if that's the entire output, then you don't have anything listening on port 8080, which would be the problem.

Comment: My process is running on `app` user and I'm running `netstat` on this same user.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This should work similar to how you have it, did you try changing:
`proxy_set_header   HOST $http_host;`
to
`proxy_set_header   HOST $host;`
in your nginx config?

You could put nginx in your Docker Compose file and let Compose use its own network. If you want to add items in another network, you can specify a custom network, see: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Otherwise, you can look at the output of `ifconfig`, etc on your host and see which IP and network Compose is using and what the host is listening to.

Comment: I don't know if it is a good practice to do so, I prefer to isolate each of my containers and running them in local and allow external traffic by proxing with Nginx on the host.

Comment: I edited my answer to more specifically address your nginx issue, depending on your set-up, that could be the culprit. The Docker discussion is a much large one, but certainly _a_ best practice would be to keep everything in Docker to make it more portable, but it's highly solution-specific. I use both methods in fact, I just don't happen to use compose when mixing them, but no reason you shouldn't be able to.

Comment: I already tried to change this configuration but I do not think it is a Nginx configuration problem.